# Newer versions of Kubernetes in AKS / ACS

Tags: azure-container-service

I've been looking into options of getting a newer version of Kubernetes in both AKS and ACS, but it seems the supported versions as of now are 1.7.7, 1.7.9, 1.8.1 and 1.8.2 (output of command az aks get-versions).

Since support for Azure is being upgraded continuously judging by the release notes of the latest version (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.9.md#azure-1) I was wondering if these versions will be available in ACS and / or AKS soon.

I realise that v1.9 is only out for 2 days now, I was looking at v1.8.5 at first :)

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no official dates as of now on when higher versions will be available Microsoft is highly invested and committed to AKS and ACS so I honestly would not be surprised if the versioning update comings shortly. In fact the updated doc was updated just a month ago so we are constantly pushing updates :)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-upgrade-cluster

You could always post the versioning question on this above doc too as the doc owners might have more information they are able to share

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that!